# Is it possible to dynamically update state inside a flow state within an AWS Step Function

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am implementing a [choice loop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-create-iterate-pattern-section.html) within a Step Function and am trying to create some safety mechanism to prevent too many loops accidentally occurring. In the docs they suggest creating a Lambda to update an iteration/count:

```js
  let index = event.iterator.index
  let step = event.iterator.step
  let count = event.iterator.count
 
  index = index + step
```

I was wondering if there was a way to dynamically update a counter within the Step Function, and avoid the need for an additional Lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native iteration is now possible with the new [States.MathAdd](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-math-operation)  intrinsic function:

```json
"counter.$": "States.MathAdd($.counter, 1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to set up a demonstration (thanks to @fedonev):

[image]

```json
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "Initial Pass",
  "States": {
    "Initial Pass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "Choice",
      "Parameters": {
        "payload.$": "$.payload",
        "safetyCount.$": "States.MathAdd($.safetyCount, 1)"
      }
    },
    "Choice": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Variable": "$.safetyCount",
          "NumericLessThan": 3,
          "Next": "Wait"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "End Pass"
    },
    "Wait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 5,
      "Next": "Initial Pass"
    },
    "End Pass": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can 'Test a New Execution' in the Step Function console with:

```json
{
  "safetyCount": 0,
  "payload": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```